# Uses of available in Swift

Tags: swift

I've going through a Ray Wenderlich tutorial for MVVM and in the view it has

```
@available(*, unavailable)
public required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init?(coder:) is not supported")
}
```

I understand providing the required init, but I cannot follow why there is @available(*, unavailable).

The *indicates that availability on all platforms - surely we had that already? Aren't we then marking it as unavailable for all platforms - in this case won't the fatalError never be executed?

I've looked at the Swift guide https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html and still don't understand this

Comment: it means the method is unavailable in all versions. That is, you cannot call it. I think the attribute usage here is a bit excessive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sometimes handy to make a piece of code unavailable without actually deleting it. Two use cases come to mind:

> • A subclass making methods of the superclass unavailable.
>  •
>   Legacy code that we need to keep in the source to keep supporting old
>   versions or documentation.

In such cases we can use Swift's available declaration attribute to tell the compiler that code using the marked object or function should not compile.

For example, if you have to subclass `NSObject` into something that has a stored constant which needs to be passed at initialization, and don't want to allow consumers to call `init` because it doesn't make sense to set a default value for the constant, you can make `init` unavailable to its consumers:

```
class Dummy: NSObject {

  let foo: String

  init(foo: String) {
    self.foo = foo
  }

  @available(*, unavailable)
  override init() {
    fatalError()
  }
}
```

---

**NOTE**

Unfortunately, as of 2.2, this kind of availability declaration is not converted into an Objective-C attribute, so Objective-C consumers will still see the methods and classes as available.

Answer (score 3):

From the link you have provided,

> The `unavailable` argument indicates that the declaration isn’t available on the specified platform. This argument can’t be used when specifying Swift version availability.

So essentially you are saying that this initialiser is unavailable on all platforms, which makes sense, as this initialiser is not implemented.

By adding this attribute, you make Swift issue an error when you try to use the initialiser, hence preventing people from calling it accidentally:

[image]